# Use an image as polyline stroke outline

Tags: wpf, image, polyline, stroke, visualbrush

I have a paint-like application, when I move the mouse it will draw a line by polyline. Now I want to replace the polyline outline with a pattern image, so when I move the mouse in the canvas it repeats that image as polyline's outline. I've already written this code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="#00FFFFFF" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
    <Polyline x:Name="polyline" StrokeThickness="20">
        <Polyline.Stroke>
            <VisualBrush >
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image Source="1.png"></Image>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Polyline.Stroke>
    </Polyline>
</Canvas>
```

The only problem is that it uses the image as an invisible background for the whole canvas and when I move the mouse that part of the background became visible! Look at this picture to get what I mean:

http://goo.gl/2wPKN

here is also my image pattern if you want to have a look:

http://goo.gl/staHt

So do you have any idea how should I use this image as my polyline outline?

Comment: Can you provide an image of how it *should* look like? What exactly does "outline" mean in your case?

Comment: I want to replace the simple line defined in polyline's stroke with a small repeated image. The result would be something like my current output (http://goo.gl/2wPKN) but the image would be repeated in polyline's path and not as the background of canvas. I hope I made myself clear, but sorry if I still don't make any sense!

Comment: Did you try a tiled brush as shown in the answer below? You may set the [ViewportUnits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewportunits.aspx) to `Absolute` and set an appropriate viewport size.

Comment: Yes I tried that answer, this code `<ImageBrush ImageSource="1.png" Viewport="1,1,1,1" TileMode="Tile" />` give the same result as before and by adding `ViewportUnits="Absolute"` it only gives a constant pink brush without any image.

Comment: Try setting Viewport to something that makes sense, like `Viewport="0,0,20,20"` or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) with a [`TileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx) set to `Tile` and a [`Viewport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport.aspx) that specifies the desired image tile size.

```
<Polyline x:Name="polyline" StrokeThickness="20">
    <Polyline.Stroke>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="1.png" TileMode="Tile"
                    ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,20,20"/>
    </Polyline.Stroke>
</Polyline>
```

Comment: Danke Clemens, it's exactly what I wanted, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it with PolyLine but with a path you can set it's stroke like this.

```
<Path StrokeThickness="10" Data="M 10,10 100,10" Stretch="Fill" Margin="81,36,251,100">
   <Path.Stroke>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="1.png" Viewport="0,0,1,1" TileMode="Tile"/>
   </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this code `<ImageBrush ImageSource="1.png" Viewport="1,1,1,1" TileMode="Tile" />` gives the same result as before and by adding `ViewportUnits="Absolute"` it only gives a constant pink brush without any image.